# Eclipse PDT, PHPUnit autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Is there a way to get PHPUnit auto-completion to work in Eclipse PDT without including the libraries in your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried putting the PHPUnit code on your project's include path?

Comment: where do i can get PHPUnit Code? Since i installed it from PEAR

Comment: In PHP Explorer, right-click PHP Include Path, hover over Include Path, select Configure Include Path....
Select the Libraries tab, click on Add Library...
User Library should be selected by default, so just click Next, check the PEAR Environment.

Answer (score 0):

[How do you add a PHP framework to code completion/assist in Eclipse PDT and can the framework be added as default for all projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903769/how-do-you-add-a-php-framework-to-code-completion-assist-in-eclipse-pdt-and-can-t)
Generally speaking in Eclipse, you can add a library or framework to code assist/completion by:

1. Going into Project > Properties
2. Under PHP Include Path, pick the "Libaries" tab.
3. Add an "external folder" with the path to where your framework is
   located.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable it.

Go to menu: `Window -> Preferences`. Then under `PHP -> Editor -> Code Assist`. From under auto activation check the `enable auto activation` check box (note: 200 ms default is a bit slow). You can adjust the timing.