# PHPUnit in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit

Having spot of bother with PHPUnit in eclipse indigo (zend php build).

found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903769/how-do-you-add-a-php-framework-to-code-completion-assist-in-eclipse-pdt-and-can) but I cannot for the life of me get code assist working at all.

Tried adding include path to project, ading library to global preferences and combinations thereof.

Any tips greatly appreciated.